# How to prove that normal matrix with property $A^2=A$ is Hermitian?

Tags: matrices

I am given a matrix $A\in M(n\times n, \mathbb{C})$ normal (in matrix form $AA^*=A^*A$) and $A^2=A$. The task is to prove that the matrix is Hermitian.

But when I try something like $A^*=\,\,...$ , then I can't reach $A$, because I can't "get rid of star" in expression. Also it is not enough to show $BA=BA^*$ for some $B$ since matrix don't form a field, and I haven't got any other thoughts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Showing that $BA=BA^*$ for some $B$ wouldn't suffice even in a field. It would suffice in any case if $B$ were invertible (or at least not a zero divisor; but those two coincide for square matrices).

Comment: I mean like in field $\forall B\neq 0\ \exists B^{-1}$.

Comment: Something looks wrong to my untrained eye.  If $A$ is invertible, then $A^2=A$ implies $A=I$.

Comment: @bob.sacamento: what's wrong with that?

Comment: @bob.sacamento $A$ isn't invertible in general

Comment: @haemhweg:  OK.  My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: by spectral theorem, a normal matrix is hermitian if and only if all its eigenvalues are real. What complex numbers have the property that they are equal to their squares?

Comment: Not just $1$, zero too!

Comment: Oh, for sure. But anyway it is real. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** By spectral theorem, a normal matrix is diagonalizable by a unitary matrix.

Then what are the eigenvalues of a diagonalizable matrix $A$ which satisfies
$$A^2=A?$$